# How to tell which ubuntu-based distribution you're on?

Tags: shell-script, kubuntu, distributions

I'm writing a script where I want different code to execute depending on the distribution. Specifically, this is a script for setting up new machines, and I would like to add the kubuntu backports repo (and a few other things like installing kubuntu-restricted-extras), but only if that machine is running kubuntu

I've seen a few methods for doing this, but they don't seem specific enough to distinguish between different ubuntu-based distros. For example:

- `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` will show ubuntu even if I'm on kubuntu
- `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` will show plasma, and `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` will show KDE, which I don't think will let me distinguish between kubuntu and KDE neon

The only way I've found that seems to work is:

```
if env | grep -q kubuntu
then
  echo "running kubuntu"
fi
```

However, that seems to be reliant on the presence of a particular config directory, which I'm not sure will remain stable between releases? Is there a more correct way to do this?

**Details**

- The script will only be run on a machine that is running some variant of ubuntu
- The key distributions I need to distinguish between are **ubuntu**, **kubuntu**, **KDE neon**, and **pop!_os**. My main confusion stems from the fact that 2 of the distros run KDE, and 2 run GNOME, so I can't simply check the DE
- I'm happy to install software to get this information, but only if its part of the standard/default repos for that distribution. For example, `neofetch` is fair game, but I hear that it sometimes [reports the incorrect name](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#linux-neofetch-reports-inaccurate-distro-name)

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). The only difference between the Ubuntu flavors is the desktop environment they use, and you can install KDE on non Kubuntu flavors as you can install non-KDE on Kubuntu. What is it you are _really_ trying to test?

Comment: Its a script to setup a freshly formatted machine, so specifically I'd like to add the kubuntu backports repo only if I'm on kubuntu. If I check strictly for the DE, then the script would add the repo if I run it on KDE neon, which would seem unwise?

Comment: In this case, I think this Ask Ubuntu Q/A might shed some light about it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives/699#699

Comment: Try `neofetch` or `dpkg -l '*buntu-desktop' | grep ^ii` but maybe it's not complete solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the details so they will be seen by the next person to read it. Also clarify how portable this needs to be. Do you need to check if you're runnign Linux, then check if you are running a version of Linux that uses `apt`, then check if that is Ubuntu, or can you be sure that all of your users will be running some form of Ubuntu?

Comment: I've edited the question to more accurately reflect what I'm looking for. I think I was confusing things before by talking about things like kubuntu vs lubuntu. I've listed the 4 specific distros I need to distinguish between. They're all ubuntu based and some use the same DE

Comment: 1. check the active (i.e. not commented out) repos listed in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files.  2. check if any defining packages are installed (e.g. those mentioned in the link given by @A.B - although I'm not entirely sure that it's up-to-date...none of the links in the accepted answer seem to work, or at none of the half-dozen or so that I tried).

Comment: @cas the question is from 2010 so indeed... Anyway here's an equivalent link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kubuntu-desktop

Comment: @A.B yeah, i'd assume not...but the answer was last edited March this year, so I'm not sure.  I suspect the links are broken because links to apps.ubuntu.com get redirected to https://snapcraft.io/

Comment: As your equivalent kubuntu-desktop link shows, the packages still exist and can be used to distinguish between different ubuntu variants

Comment: I tend to agree with @terdon, though, that it's an XY problem.  If the system that the OP is running this script on is "freshly installed", then they should know what they just installed.  Provide that as a command-line argument to the script.  easy, accurate, no ambiguities.

Comment: @simon - Every distro release I have worked on has a file in the /etc dirctory that has "release" or "version" in its name.  Ubuntu has two: `lsb-release` and `os-release`.  Can you parse those files to get the information you are looking for?  (The naming convention will vary between distros.)